# Social Media Dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I need to make single page social media dashboard using kibana and elasticsearch for some big event in 2019, so that the dashboard show hom many likes it has on facebook or instagram, how many people are going etc (and some other informations ). I dont have much experience with kibana and elasticsearch so any advice would be helpfull. Any idea how can I do that ?. Also I need to have heatmap in the dashboard. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

That is a pretty broad question. Do you already have the relevant data in Elasticsearch? Because that would be the starting point.

For the visualization you could use a dashboard or the more customizable [Canvas](https://www.elastic.co/products/stack/canvas), which is pretty much like a data driven Powerpoint:

[image]

Comment: I can't use some API or something ? I dont know how to start. There is not too much tutorials for kibana on the internet.

Comment: No, the first thing you need to do for Kibana to work is to store the Tweets in Elasticsearch.